# How to auto-scroll to the bottom of a DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor control?

Tags: asp.net, html, devexpress

I have been wrestling with this for hours and just can't make it work. I'm using an ASPxHtmlEditor to display (in Preview mode) a dynamically constructed table (that is increasing its rows over the time). I need the control to be scrolled always on the bottom of the table. I have tried using this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>window.scrollTo(0, document.body.offsetHeight);</script>
```

It works on a web page (or a Web Form) but not inside the HTML code in the control. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following bit of code: 
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q207598.aspx

Comment: Thanks Rachel, the solution on that link worked for me. It is a javascript function on the client-side event Init of the ASPxHtmlEditor.